# Php get content without question mark?

Tags: php

I get mysite.com/?file=abc

```
<?php if(!empty($_GET['file'])) {?>
<?php echo $_GET['file']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

it's possible get value like this:
mysite.com/file/abc

Comment: Yes, you should use a pretty URL in your project.

Comment: if you are using **Apache** you'll need to use the **rewrite** module. the concept is sometimes called pretty url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache, and your config allows for htaccess overrides,
you can create an .htaccess file like this

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

URL

```
mysite.com/file/abc
```

In your php file do something like this

```
<?php
$query = explode('/', $_GET['q']);

if ($query[0] === 'file') {
   echo $query[1];
}
```